# Cannot edit newly added object

Tags: objects, 3d-view, windows

I am fairly new to blender and I cannot seem to solve this issue;

Whenever I **add a new object**. I used to get this sort of menu. in the tools section on the right.

[image]

However, after working on my file for about an hour. I **cannot access this menu** upon adding a new object.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a workaround is to press F6 after adding the object in.